# Wind resistance

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics

You have a metal plate/sign (max weight $5\, \text{kg}$) $1200\, \text{mm}$ long and $400\, \text{mm}$ high pivot/hinge at its base. A windspeed of $90 - 100\, \text{km/h}$ is applied to one face of the sign.

What force would be required to prevent it blowing over?

Comment: where should the force be applied?

Comment: The force would be applied to the opposite side in the form of a gas strut. These range from 20 - 2500Nm however nobody has been able to tell me what force is required to maintain the sign in a vertical position.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or is the question just asking what force does a 90-100 kmh wind produce on the sign?

Comment: Yes I guess. Surely the size of the sign comes into it somewhere? I found something that says the speed is proportionate to the force so 90 - 100km is 25 - 27.77 meters a second then that's 25 - 27.77 Nm required to stop the sign blowing over???

Comment: I think the best aproach here is to compute the torsion due to the wind on the sign (assume the wind deposits all it's momentum on the sign). The it's a simple procedure to compute the strength of the force on the other side to obtain the same torsion.

Answer (score 1):

The drag force can be estimated by the following expression:

$$F_D=\frac12 \rho v^2C_DA$$

With $F_D$ the drag force, $\rho$ the density of the fluid, $v$ the velocity of the fluid, $A$ the cross-section of the object (perpendicular to flow) and $C_D$ the drag coefficient.

This [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient#General) gives a value of $C_D=1.28$ for a flat plat perpendicular to the airflow (wind).

This should allow you to estimate $F_D$ for your stated case. Note that all parameters must be expressed in SI units ($\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{kg}, \mathrm{s}$) (except for $C_D$ which is dimensionless) to obtain the force in $\mathrm{Newton}$.

A simple force diagram will then allow you to calculate the force needed to keep the sign in place.

Comment: The density of air at sea level is about 1.2 kg/m^3 (1.2 kilo grams per cubic meter) 0.5x1.2x27.7778x27.7778x0.48x1.28=26.667Newtons